# Python XML output with quotes

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Straight to the point.

Following python script returns the out as

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<Class><Domains>Domain name is &amp;quot;A&amp;quot;</Domains></Class>
```

But I need output XML exactly like below.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<Class><Domains>Domain name is &quot;A&quot;</Domains></Class>
```

Code

```
 from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
 def main():
    etree.register_namespace("esri","http://www.esri.com/schemas/ArcGIS/10.0")
    root = etree.XML('<Class></Class>')
    root.append(etree.Element("Domains"))
    s = "Domain name is &quot;A&quot;"
    root[0].text = s
    print etree.tostring(root, encoding='iso-8859-1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks,

Srav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You handed ET a string with `&` that needed escaping, and that's what it did. Hand it the unescaped string instead.

```
s = 'Domain name is "A"'
```

If you want to encode the quote, you can use the `cgi` module

```
>>> cgi.escape('Domain name is "A"', quote=True)
'Domain name is &quot;A&quot;'
```

If the string already has `&quot;` in it, you can unescape it before you hand it to ET

```
>>> HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape('Domain name is &quot;A&quot;')
u'Domain name is "A"'
```

Comment: This outputs `<Class><Domains>Domain name is "A"</Domains></Class>`, not exactly what he wanted.

Comment: unfortunately i don't think this works, either. After you unescape it still gets "wrongly" escaped by `to_string`.